# PHP: scrape non-english html pages

Tags: php, character-encoding, non-english

I am trying to parse some non-english pages and extract relevant information and then show the extracted information in a different html pages. However I can successfully extract relevant text using PHP Dom parser(simple_html_dom), however I am not able to show extracted text in original language. 
I have made simple script that would simply get text from URL and show

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$html = str_get_html(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.bhaskar.com/article-ht/INT-washington-capitol-hill-shooting-suspected-woman-shot-dead-by-police-4393270-PHO.html')));
echo $html;
```

I have also attached screen shot of how texts are shown.[image]

How can I show the extracted text in their original language? I would really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1):

By not adding mysterious string manipulation routines, and not `utf8_encode` already utf8_encoded content :)

```
<?
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.bhaskar.com/article-ht/INT-washington-capitol-hill-shooting-suspected-woman-shot-dead-by-police-4393270-PHO.html');
?>
```

works perfectly well here, sitting on Denmark, only pasting the above into an empty php file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for information. However check this one [pre]<?
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.thesamaja.com/news_view.php?news_id=56265');
?>[/pre]